# Field is required, when it's not defined as so

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django model

```
class Component(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children"
    )
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="components"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="component_images", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and the viewset looks like this

```
class ComponentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ComponentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Component.objects.all()
        vessel_id = self.kwargs.get("vessel_id", None)
        if vessel_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(vessel_id=vessel_id)
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(parent=None) | Q(parent__isnull=True))
        return queryset

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, vessel_id=None):
        queryset = Component.objects.all()
        component = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk, vessel_id=vessel_id)
        serializer = ComponentSerializer(component)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None, vessel_id=None, partial=True):
        queryset = Component.objects.all()
        component = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk, vessel_id=vessel_id)
        serializer = ComponentSerializer(component, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["delete"])
    def delete_component(self, request, pk=None, vessel_id=None):
        queryset = Component.objects.all()
        component = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk, vessel_id=vessel_id)

        # Recursively delete all children of the component
        self._delete_children(component)

        # Delete the component itself
        component.delete()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def _delete_children(self, component):
        children = component.children.all()
        for child in children:
            self._delete_children(child)
            child.delete()
```

The serializer:

```
class ImageSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None
        if settings.MEDIA_URL in value.url:
            return (
                settings.BASE_URL
                + settings.MEDIA_URL
                + value.url[len(settings.MEDIA_URL) :]
            )
        return value.url

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data


class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data


class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)
    image = ImageSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is my simple React form to create a component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { api } from "../../../../../userAuth/auth";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
const ComponentData = () => {
  const { vessel_id } = useParams();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    vessel: vessel_id,
    name: "",
    manufacturer: "",
    model: "",
    type: "",
    serial_number: "",
    supplier: "",
    description: "",
    image: null,
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      image: file,
    }));
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const { children, ...data } = formData; // Exclude the 'children' field

      const response = await api.post(
        `/maintenance/${vessel_id}/components/`,
        data
      );

      // TODO: Handle successful creation (e.g., show success message, redirect, etc.)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating component:", error);
      // TODO: Handle error (e.g., show error message, etc.)
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formData.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Manufacturer:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="manufacturer"
          value={formData.manufacturer}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Model:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="model"
          value={formData.model}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Type:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="type"
          value={formData.type}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Serial Number:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="serial_number"
          value={formData.serial_number}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Supplier:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="supplier"
          value={formData.supplier}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Description:
        <textarea
          name="description"
          value={formData.description}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Image:
        <input
          type="file"
          name="image"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={handleImageChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Create Component</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ComponentData;
```

Whenever I send the post request I receive Bad request. When I check the request console inside there is this.

```
response
: 
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
data
: 
children
: 
['This field is required.']
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I assume it's talking about the recursive field parent, but I already stated in my model it's not required so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can you share the serializer? Why do you override all actions yourself? This makes the API hard to maintain and adapt to authentication, authorization, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i included the serializer, regarding overriding i had to or at least i think i do(kindly point what i can change) being a recursive field caused a bit of a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the serializer, where your `image` and `children` field did not specify if these are required, and if not, by default they are. For the `children`, if I understand it correctly, these will only be used to read, so add `read_only=…` to prevent to use these in the `RecursiveField`:

```
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    image = ImageSerializerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = '__all__'
```

The implementation for the `RecursiveField` also likely does not work for all cases, for example without a `many=True`, this will definitely fail since there is no `parent` for the `parent`. You might want to use [**`django-rest-framework-recursive`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive), which [proxies most attributes <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive/blob/e114cea9253412ab25168ac4c1c2db59493b6d36/rest_framework_recursive/fields.py#L18-L127).

Finally the serializer does *way* too much. Most of what you do is boilerplate. For example removing all the children and subchildren, etc. will be handled by Django's ORM, and in a more efficient manner. By doing this, you also make it harder later to perform proper authentication, authorization, throttling, etc. The `ModelViewSet` already has boilerplate logic to get a list, a specific item, etc.

```
class ComponentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Component.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ComponentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        vessel_id = self.kwargs.get('vessel_id')
        if vessel_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(vessel_id=vessel_id)
        return queryset.filter(parent=None)
```

that is all we need.

Comment: Thank you, that actually made a lot of sense.